# Django не видит Postgres из docker-compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

делаю композ для джанго и постгреса, но джанго не видит постгрес на 5432 порте

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .envs/docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
    - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .envs/docker.env
    ports:
    - "8001:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc libffi-dev g++

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.3

# App directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
RUN python -m venv /venv

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && poetry install --no-root

COPY . .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Скрипт пытается запустить сервер, но не может из-за отсутствия бд. Всё, что я вижу это

[image: ошибка]

1. Окружение настроено правильно и переменные окружения попадают правильно
2. Контейнер бд запускается и работает. Об этом говорится в логах и я с хоста могу подключиться по 8001 порту
3. В бд даже не приходит реквест об авторизации, пинг из контейнера джанго говорит, что порты пусты
4. Пытался открывать, закрывать порты через композ и докерфайл, тоже не помогло

Наверное, тут нужно что-то делать через `network`. Но во всех доках используется обычный практически такой докерфайл

Comment: Вообще странно.. Вы пытались пройти именно тот туториал, на который ссылались (у Вас тут, как я понял, немного другое)? Я его прошел и у меня никаких проблем не возникло (только версию компоуз файла пришлось поменять, потому как у меня 3.8 не поддерживается). Дело в том, что компоуз создает дефолтную сеть для всех контейнеров, которые им запускаются. Т.е. можно и без указания неворка обойтись.

Comment: @AlexeyR. пример из тех доков у меня не сработал. Но не сработал он только по причине того, что не было линковки адреса контейнера. Видимо, хоть они и на одной сети (вероятно), но в любом случае нужно указывать links, что бы использовать его как адрес

Comment: @AlexeyR. Понял свою ошибку. В имени хоста указывал не имя сервиса (db), а localhost или 0.0.0.0. В документации докера прочитал, что по дефолту есть прокси по имени контейнера, об этом я не знал. Links это просто дополнительные алиасы для удобства, однако даже с ними по имени сервиса можно обрататиться. Надеюсь, это поможет другим